# Не получаеться многогопточнoе приложение через omp (как добавить флаг -Wall в QtCreator)

Tags: c, многопоточность, qtcreator, openmp

Пытаюсь запустить пару потоков. Чтоб разобраться как они работают. Но вот оказаия "работает" только один поток В [Qt(qthread class)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) это всё несколько проще, притом в qthread нету "завязки" потоков на количество ядер, а [тут](https://www.openmp.org/) как я (пока) предполагаю, строгая "завязка" на количество ядер.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(){
    int x[1000]; int i;
    omp_set_dynamic(0);      // запретить библиотеке openmp менять число потоков во время исполнения
    omp_set_num_threads(10); // установить число потоков  10
    // инициализируем массив
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    // выводим тексту
//    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(x) // не сработало
//    #pragma omp parallel for shared(x) private(i) // не сработало

#pragma omp parallel for shared(x, i) 
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf("Запущен поток %d: x = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),x[i]);

    int myid, a;
    a = 10;
#pragma omp parallel default(private) \ firstprivate(a)
    {
        myid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread%d: a = %d\n", myid, a);
        a = myid;
        printf("Thread%d: a = %d\n", myid, a);
    }

#pragma omp parallel private(myid)
    {
        myid = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for private(i)
        for(i=0; i<8; i++)
#pragma omp ordered
            printf("T%d: %d\n", myid, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот результат

```
...
Запущен поток 0: x = 988
Запущен поток 0: x = 989
Запущен поток 0: x = 990
Запущен поток 0: x = 991
Запущен поток 0: x = 992
Запущен поток 0: x = 993
Запущен поток 0: x = 994
Запущен поток 0: x = 995
Запущен поток 0: x = 996
Запущен поток 0: x = 997
Запущен поток 0: x = 998
Запущен поток 0: x = 999
Thread0: a = 10
Thread0: a = 0
T0: 0
T0: 1
T0: 2
T0: 3
T0: 4
T0: 5
T0: 6
T0: 7
Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...
```

---

Спасибо, @Vladimir благодаря вам я заметил, что QtCreator игнорирует `#pragma omp`

Стал менять файл проекта `.pro` но увы не выходит ;_;

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
#CONFIG += all
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wall

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpthread

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lomp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include
```

Что я делаю не так ??

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос опции сборки и каким компилятором собираете. Еще, в `#pragma omp parallel for shared(x, i) ` не нужно `i` относить к общим переменным, насколько я помню, счетчик цикла должен быть локальным (обычно его вообще можно не описывать и компилятор сам правильно назначает ему свойства).

Comment: @АмирЗакиров  обновил вопрос

Comment: Еще мелкие ошибки: `#pragma omp parallel default(private) \ firstprivate(a)` - там не должно быть бэкслеша и `default` может принимать аргументом либо `shared`, либо `none`. приватность же там подразумевается по умолчанию. И второе: меня `g++` попросил в последнем блоке добавить `ordered` к описанию цикла, иначе не компилирует: `#pragma omp for private(i) ordered`. И после устранения мелких косяков - все работает в 10 потоков (ну, где просят).

Comment: @Vladimir компилировал в gcc. возможно проблема в операционной (ubuntu)

Comment: `g++ prog.cpp -o proga -O2 -fopenmp` - и все работает. Mingw-w64, gcc 7.3. Нет, Ubuntu не виновата.

Comment: @Vladimir так этож плюсы ))

Comment: Да не проблема, могу и в чистом Си собрать.

Comment: Запустил VirtualBox с Xubuntu 14.04.5, собрал как программу на Си `gcc prog.c -o proga -O2 -fopenmp` - все-равно все работает. Вы может чего-то недоустановили в комплекте к gcc? но тогда бы gcc ругался на опции/недостающие библиотеки..

Comment: @Vladimir странно работаю в ubuntu 18  собирал всё в QtCreator-e но я также напрямую из консоли запускал. Возможно из за памяти ( 2 гига оперативки на компе), хотя не думаю.

Comment: Пошел в виртуальную Xubuntu 18.04 LTS и там тоже проверил - работает :-). У виртуалки с памятью тоже не очень, так что, нет, 2Гб не виновато. Как и сама Ubuntu. Все-таки, какой командой собираете программу? Добавьте еще опцию `-Wall` - может при сборке на что-то ругнется?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не было недопонимания, раз уж я немного модифицировал текст программы, то приведу его в ответе. Но если подходить строго, изменения нужны были для сборки программы, а не потому, что это влияет на многопоточность.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(){
    int x[1000]; int i;
    omp_set_dynamic(0);      // запретить библиотеке openmp менять число потоков во время исполнения
    omp_set_num_threads(10); // установить число потоков  10
    // инициализируем массив
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    // выводим тексту
//    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(x) // не сработало
//    #pragma omp parallel for shared(x) private(i) // не сработало

#pragma omp parallel for shared(x) 
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf("Запущен поток %d: x = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),x[i]);

    int myid, a;
    a = 10;
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(a) // default(private)
    {
        myid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread%d: a = %d\n", myid, a);
        a = myid;
        printf("Thread%d: a = %d\n", myid, a);
    }

#pragma omp parallel private(myid)
    {
        myid = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp for private(i) ordered
        for(i=0; i<8; i++)
 #pragma omp ordered
            printf("T%d: %d\n", myid, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Сборку программы проводил командой: `gcc prog.c -o prog -O2 -fopenmp -Wall`.

Результат (всю простыню не выведу, только несколько строк, лишнее удалял наугад, но чтобы было видно, что потоки с разными номерами):

```
Запущен поток 3: x = 300
Запущен поток 3: x = 301
Запущен поток 1: x = 101
Запущен поток 2: x = 200
Запущен поток 6: x = 600
Запущен поток 6: x = 607
Запущен поток 6: x = 615
Запущен поток 2: x = 207
Запущен поток 1: x = 115
Запущен поток 7: x = 700
Запущен поток 6: x = 616
Запущен поток 7: x = 701
Запущен поток 6: x = 623
Запущен поток 8: x = 825
Запущен поток 8: x = 840
Запущен поток 0: x = 39
Запущен поток 0: x = 68
Запущен поток 0: x = 91
Запущен поток 4: x = 400
Запущен поток 2: x = 267
Запущен поток 3: x = 333
Запущен поток 9: x = 919
Запущен поток 1: x = 175
Запущен поток 9: x = 998
Запущен поток 9: x = 999
Thread6: a = 10
Thread6: a = 6
Thread5: a = 10
Thread5: a = 5
Thread2: a = 10
Thread7: a = 10
Thread8: a = 8
Thread1: a = 10
Thread8: a = 10
Thread8: a = 8
Thread8: a = 8
Thread3: a = 10
Thread3: a = 3
Thread7: a = 7
Thread4: a = 10
Thread4: a = 4
Thread0: a = 10
Thread0: a = 0
Thread9: a = 10
Thread9: a = 9
T0: 0
T1: 1
T2: 2
T3: 3
T4: 4
T5: 5
T6: 6
T7: 7
```

**UPD:**

В интернетах советуют сделать такие опции сборки в QtCreator:

```
QMAKE_LIBS+=-static -lgomp -lpthread" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-msse3 -fopenmp" QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-U_WIN32
```

то есть Вам нужно для `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` (для Си соответственно, `QMAKE_CFLAGS`) добавить опцию `-fopenmp` - без нее компилятор не будет обрабатывать соответствующие прагмы.

Comment: Наверное  я понял проблему QtCreator игнорирует прагму  , нужен флаг `-Wall` . Но я не знаю как его установить  флаг`-Wall` в QtCreator-e.

Comment: @timob256, -Wall - это чтобы выводило ворнинги от компилятора, оно не имеет отношения к прагмам. И я не думаю, что QtCreator как-то блокирует прагму.. В любом случае, сначала попробуйте собирать в консоли с нужными параметрами, а уже потом переходите к борьбе с Creatorom.